# Why was my post deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

For the question *[Compiler segmentation fault while using Set in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531754)*, my answer was:

> Playgrounds have always been buggy for me unfortunately. Not many
>   others have this issue, but I do get errors like this from time to
>   time.
>
> As a result I either use https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net or use
>   Playground with *caution* or use Xcode.

I'm assuming it was because the person who deleted it, thought it should have been a comment. This isn't one of those "me too" answers. To me it's like those questions where someone is asking why this feature isn't this iOS feature working and the answer is, this is a known issue, bug, etc., and you just most cope with it!

So should it still be deleted?

**Long story short, how do you post an answer for a bug related question?**

What I did was, 1. confirm that it's a bug, 2 offered alternatives.

**EDIT:**

I added 5 links to show similar issues with Playground.

**EDITED to add links:**

> Playgrounds is a bit buggy. Some others have run into un-reproducable
>   issues. I also get errors like this from time to time. Usually the fix
>   is to close Xcode, change your cursor's position etc.
>
> Some similar folks with playground issues and some suggestions on how
>   to solve them:
>
> Xcode playground gets stuck on 'Running playground' or 'Launching
>   simulator' and won't run the code, what to do?
>
> I highly recommend you to see this question first:
>
> [XCode hangs every time when i write few lines of code in playground](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31007759/5175709)
>
> Then also see these posts (some of the links are old, but still
>   Playground isn't that mature yet):
>
> https://teamtreehouse.com/community/xcode-playground-gets-stuck-on-running-and-wont-run-the-code-what-to-do
>
> https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/playground-hangs-frequently/7331
>
> https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75045
>
> [failed to launch stub for playground execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877419/failed-to-launch-stub-for-playground-execution)
>
> --- As a result I either use https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net or use Playground with caution or use Xcode. Usually it's best to use the
>   latest Xcode so likely you would have the least amount of bugs...

Then I tried vote it to be reopened, but since it was closed by a moderator, I couldn't do that. So I opened a new answer with those links.

<sub>My new answer isn't a repost. It did look like that because I initially made the edit on my original answer so I could vote for reopening... Then I reposted the same **edited** answer as my new answer. Which resulted in another deletion :(</sub>

Comment: So your answer doesn't try to answer the question, and you know it's not trying to answer the question and that it should have been a comment instead.  So...why are you questioning its deletion?  You just gave the reason why it merits deletion in your question here.

Comment: I fail to see how it changes anything.  You still know that you weren't attempting to answer the question asked, and you know that, since you weren't posting an answer, you should have posted a comment, even if you apparently don't agree with that policy.  You still don't need us to tell you why your answer was deleted.

Comment: servy, how do you post an answer to a bug question?!!!!

Comment: You are not saying "this is a known issue". If you were saying that, and referring to which particular issue was impacting the OP question, would be a different thing altogether. As it is; your answer is more like "me too, but link".

Comment: How does *Playgrounds have always been buggy for me unfortunately. Not many others have this issue, but I do get errors like this time to time.* confirm that it's a bug?

Comment: You didn't confirm any bug. You just said "_Playgrounds have always been buggy for me_", which is a far cry from actual **confirmation**.

Comment: @yivi 
"Playgrounds have always been buggy for me unfortunately. Not many others have this issue, but I do get errors like this from time to time." Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877419/failed-to-launch-stub-for-playground-execution)

Comment: @Honey Since the question is asking if it's a bug or if they're doing something wrong, you should either confirm that it's a known bug (and providing evidence to support this position, by either referring to an acknowledgement of the company that it's a bug, or a reference to the specs that it violates (or similar), or confirming that it's not a bug by explaining why the behavior is within specs (or similar).  All you said was that you have the same problem, which doesn't explain whether it's a bug or you're just both doing something wrong.

Comment: @NathanOliver maybe it's because of my lack of proper English, how would have to convey that, please do elaborate!

Comment: @Honey: _"I'm having trouble walking the stairs too, try an elevator"_  is not an confirmation that the __stairs__ are broken. It may even suggest __I__ am broken for being unable to use the stairs.

Comment: @yivi I do see a difference, but just because someone posted something makes it valid reference? if that's the case, then me posting it as a known issue, makes it valid!

Comment: @Cerbrus Worse still, it doesn't even confirm that the stairs are fine.  Saying, "the stairs are functioning properly, but I personally don't like the intended behavior so I take elevators instead" would be an answer, but "I distrust stairs because they're so often broken, so I take elevators instead" doesn't actually tell you if a given staircase is in good condition or not.

Comment: @Honey You need to prove it is a bug.  Finding a bug report, showing a different version works fine, proving by the spec that it should work.  That is how you show it is a bug and then you can advise on alternatives.

Comment: @Honey You didn't say it was a known issue.  You said that you think the product is buggy in general, not that the specific behavior identified is in violation of the product's own specs.  If you did *that* then the post would be a [bad] answer.  For it to be a *good* answer it would need to support that assertion by explaining *why* it's a bug, either by pointing to the section of the specs it violates, an acknowledgement that it's a bug by the owner, etc.

Comment: And even if the stairs are in good condition, they might still be [utterly unusable.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a3/Escher%27s_Relativity.jpg)

Comment: @NathanOliver so if I went and filed a radar with Apple myself and then linked that myself, that would be proved as a bug?! That makes no sense! If you looked into the comments of his question you would see others say his code is working for them. I've ran into similar weird issues with playground as well...

Comment: @Honey No that wouldn't work.  You'd need to find a confirmed bug report, not one you wrote up yourself.

Comment: @NathanOliver How would you tell the difference? If it wasn't me? Bug reports are just reports. Any person can file a bug... Bug reports are generated by people like me and you. SO can also function as a substitute

Comment: It would be confirmed if a developer at Apple confirmed your report. It's not so bizarre. Reported != Confirmed.

Comment: @yivi I've seen answers on SO before that are not confirmed and yet are answers...I'll have dig deep to find them. But if I do, would you then be satisfied that there is a bit of a double standard on SO?

Comment: You could even answer with an unconfirmed bug that you know from experience. But even then, your answer should explain what behavior you found, and in which way it was buggy (and how it impacted the OPs question). Just saying "I think this product is buggy", no dice.

Comment: @Honey: Please back up your claims (_"I've seen..."_) with some links. This is just turning into a _"he said, she said"_ argument that isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @yivi how do you explain if the same exact code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't?! I can only think of saying it's buggy. Because I'm not changing anything to find a parameter. The only thing that is changing is others apps running, the time of the day, the position of my laptop...

Comment: It might as well be something else on your machine that's causing the issue.

Comment: @Cerbrus do you really think I'm just some guy on his happy hours, posting answers like this for fun?! I've see the bug. I've asked other friends, 'some' have seen it infrequently. What you're saying is, until no one else sees/confirms the bug online, then 'yours' doesn't count. Had I been some one with 250K reps, then you would have agreed...

Comment: @Honey, rep is irrelevant. I __don't care__ what rep someone has if they post a low quality answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus nope, it still happened after I wiped my machine clean and installed the OS, the Xcode. The only thing I can think of is that I'm using Xcode 8.2.1, but even then there isn't a report for it. Wasn't reported before, still isn't reported

Comment: _"something else"_ can also be hardware. Not reported yet? So report it.

Comment: Reposting the answer while this is ongoing probably won't work out well for you.

Comment: @Will I didn't repost the same answer, I added 5 links to point out it's a known issue. That it isn't just me...If you think that's wrong, please elaborate, I used the comments here to improve my answer.

Comment: Would have been better to edit and have the original undeleted... glad to know you did get some confirmation links tho.

Comment: None of the links _confirm_ it's a bug. It's only a few people having the same issue. None of the posts seem tob e from this year.

Comment: @Cerbrus what's the difference between a 'bug' and an 'issue'?

Comment: @Honey: That difference isn't the point here. Someone can call it a bug, but that doesn't mean anything until it's ___confirmed___ by the author of the product to be a issue __in said product__.

Comment: I deleted your repost too, it has even more problems than the original in that you only copied the title for one of your links, not the link itselves.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair enough. I won't repost again. I'll just ask a question about what is the difference between 'issue and bug'. Because I honestly don't know!

Comment: There is no practical difference in the scope of this discussion, IMO. You report issues or bugs, the developer confirms them, rejects them, ignores them, etc. [Different software or methodologies will use one name or another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179658/what-are-the-differences-among-bugs-issues-and-tasks-in-tfs).

Comment: _@Honey: That difference isn't the point here._

Comment: @MartijnPieters Let me just **clarify** something. The original post I wrote, I made a **substantial edit** and added references to back up my claim. Then tried to vote it for reopening, in which I couldn't! Because it was deleted by a moderator. Therefore I opened a new answer. My point my original answer and my new answer are very much different. Does that make any difference for you? (I've reverted the changes of my original answer...)

Comment: @Honey, maybe it is time to focus on answering a different question?

Comment: @yivi you could move away from this thread, or vote for deletion of this thread. I did "[backup my claim](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357363/why-was-my-post-deleted/357364?noredirect=1#comment519011_357363)" by providing references

Comment: @Honey, it wasn't meant as an attack, please don't take it the wrong way. I just meant that you are spending an inordinate amount of energy trying to answer and getting your answer deleted. It might be more productive (for you), to spend more time at a different post, so all the arguments people are making about the deletion have time to sink in. Peace.

Comment: @Honey: it does and it doesn't. You can flag your old answer for moderator attention to request undeleting. I did miss that you had edited the old post significantly, for example, so it looked like a straight-up repost to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. I edited it and flagged it.

Comment: @Honey Even your second answer *still hasn't answered the question*.  The OP is asking if the given behavior they're seeing is a bug, and your response to that is to say, "here are some bugs that this program has that are entirely unrelated to what you're seeing and don't explain what is happening to you, so you should use this other tool because it doesn't have bugs."  That's not answering the question of whether the behavior the OP is seeing is due to a bug or improper use of the tool.  If you were linking to references that showed that what the OP is seeing is a bug, you'd have an answer.

Comment: Well, technically if you linked to other sources explaining that the OP's behavior is a bug you'd have a link only answer, which would still merit deletion.  If you used such a reference to support an explanation *in the answer* of why the behavior the OP is seeing is a bug, *then* you'd have an answer.

Comment: Oh, and answers don't get closed or reopened.  Your answer is *deleted*, not closed.  You're asking for it to be *undeleted*, not reopened.

Comment: @yivi You're absolutely right. But each time I try to assert my opinions to full understand the community rules. And even if I don't understand/like what the community says, I at least *know* the community better and write less answers/questions/comments the community doesn't like (even though I like myself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've heavily edited and undeleted the answer, because I think it now meets the threshold of something that a moderator should not unilaterally delete.

Whether it's a *useful* answer is not a determination that I am qualified to make, nor is it one that moderators should be making in response to flags.

I will say, though, that I remain concerned that the question is not actually about Playgrounds. It appears to be about an internal compiler error. So, while workarounds to a compiler bug are certainly valid answers *in general*, I'm not sure that your answer is relevant to the question that was asked. Also, contrary to the claim made in your question, the answer does *not* confirm that the behavior is a compiler bug. It merely points out that others are having problems with Playgrounds. You never make the connection between the problem in the question and the problems with Playgrounds that you (and the linked others) have experienced.

I'll defer judgment on that to the community. In particular, trusted experts on Swift and/or XCode, who can cast downvotes and delete votes.

As far as the *initial* deletion, I definitely understand the concerns of the flaggers and moderator involved. On the other hand, I'm a bit concerned about the line of thinking expressed by others here, including Cerbrus. Perhaps I misunderstand, but it seems to me that if this were carried to its logical conclusion, it would suggest that answers proposing workarounds are not valid answers. This is certainly *incorrect*. If you post a question about a compiler bug, then a workaround to avoid the compiler bug in the original environment *is* an answer—even a *good* answer—as would be an answer recommending an alternative compiler/environment that did not suffer from the bug. There seems to have been a knee-jerk reaction over the length of your answer in its original form, and the fact that it included a link. That the link *was* the answer appears to have been missed. This wasn't a case where the answer was buried *behind* the link, [which is what we mean when we casually speak of "link-only" answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).

Answer (score 18):

*"I'm having this problem too, but I use this tool instead"* doesn't actually answer the question.

It should've been a comment instead.

Comment: "this is a known issue, bug, etc and you just most cope with it!" I've seen many answers like that

Comment: I saw your edit, but I don't think that invalidates this answer. Your answer doesn't answer the question. Your confirmation is anecdotal at best. The alternatives you provide aren't very well written... Look at the workaround the remaining answer describes.

Comment: Not sure I agree with this. Proposing a *workaround* for a problem is always an acceptable answer, even if it's not the one that the asker ultimately prefers.

Comment: @CodyGray: I wouldn't call linking to a different IDE / tool a "workaround".

Comment: Sure. I'm not defending the answer in its original state. I just don't agree that suggesting a tool to work around a problem cannot be an answer to the question.

Comment: @CodyGray Without actually explaining why a different tool works (and why the tool the OP is using doesn't), it ends up being little more than a tool recommendation.

Comment: @yivi You are still talking about how to compose a *good* answer. I'm not arguing about that. What I'm saying is that recommending a tool that works around the problem *is* an answer. Cerbrus's answer appears to me to be making the claim that such can never be an answer.

Comment: @Cody, IMO, Cerbrus answer makes the claim that answers in the vein of "_me too, but please see this other link_" should be posted as comments, not answers. I don't derive the general idea that no tool recommendation can be made under any circumstance.

Comment: My delete; this answer sums up  reasoning. It'd be a decent comment, but I have a hard time seeing it as an answer - and I'm traditionally harder to convince about NAA. It's definitely not the clearest case, and I did spend far more time than usual looking at it, but in the end I called it NAA, or at least very VLQ.

Comment: @Undo did you look into my 2nd answer? It shows enough references that it's a known issue. Also proposed alternative solutions.

Comment: Can't look closely right now @Honey, busy at work. I'll defer to Martijn on that one.

Comment: @CodyGray Saying, "Yes, that's a bug, and you can use this other tool to do what you want as it doesn't have that bug" is an answer, just as saying, "no, it's not a bug, but you can use this other tool that makes it easier/possible to do [....]" is also an answer, but saying, "I have no idea what the answer to your question is, but you can just use this other tool instead" isn't actually answering the question.

Comment: @Servy "I've had the same problem in the past, and while I was unable to determine the cause, I ended up using this other tool that doesn't have that issue." seems like a reasonable answer to me. It isn't a good answer by any means, but it is an answer.